# Apply walker_nav_menu_start_el but only to one menu

Tags: navigation, accessibility

I'm building an accessible dropdown menu and successfully created a button to toggle the menu for screen readers that doesn't interfere with a top-level link. I targeted the class `menu-item-has-children` to do this, and thought I was applying it to only one menu, but it's showing up in the footer where I don't want or need it. Looking for a way to only apply this in `wp_nav_menu` when a specific walker is applied.

```
// ADD SUBMENU BUTTON FOR A11Y
    function test_menu_arrow($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
        $aria_label = $item->title;
        $aria_controls = $item->ID;
        $arrow = '<button class="sub-menu-btn" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sub-menu-'.$aria_controls.'" aria-label="More '.$aria_label.'"></button>';
        $item_output = str_replace('</a>', '</a>'. $arrow .'', $item_output);
    }
        return $item_output;
    }
    add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'test_menu_arrow', 10, 4);
```

Comment: You should be able to read that out of the `$args` object. The walker property(`$args->walker`) should be populated with your walker name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was easy. leaving here if someone stumbles upon this and it's useful OR if someone has a better solution. In the comments below - the first if statement designates we only want this to apply to our mega menu which in our case is menu-2 in theme_location of wp_nav_menu

```
// ADD SUBMENU BUTTON FOR A11Y
    add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'test_menu_arrow', 10, 4);
    function test_menu_arrow($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // ** The next 2 lines are the UPDATE see notes **
    if ( empty( $args->theme_location ) || 'menu-2' !== $args->theme_location ) {
        return $item_output;
    }
        if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
        $aria_label = $item->title;
        $aria_controls = $item->ID;
        $arrow = '<button class="sub-menu-btn" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sub-menu-'.$aria_controls.'" aria-label="More '.$aria_label.'"></button>';
        $item_output = str_replace('</a>', '</a>'. $arrow .'', $item_output);
    }
        return $item_output;
    }
```

Comment: Suggest you edit the answer to indicate what you changed / added.